# Heap's Algorithm in C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I've been working on implementing a recursive version of heap's algorithm. Here is the link to the pseudocode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Everything has been going fine until I get to the recursive part. I know I haven't put in swapping elements yet but I haven't gotten that far. The run fails without showing an error until I use the gcc debugger which tells me that there has been a segmentation fault. Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string* permute(int n, string array[2]){
    if (n==1){
        return array;
    }
    else{
        for(int c=1; c<=n;c++){
            permute(n--,array);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string array[2]={"a","b"};
    permute(2,array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is the return statement in the `else` part of function `permute`? And why are you decrementing `n` inside the loop which runs from `1` to `n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let aside the fact that the entire implementation seems wrong, the direct reason for the runtime exception that you're experiencing is your recursive call to `permute(2,array)`, which eventually leads to a stack overflow. This happens because you are calling it with `n--` instead of `--n` (or more precisely, `n-1`).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm a beginner so help is always appreciated!

Comment: @user2514631: You're welcome :) There's a lot more work to be done up there.

Answer (score 2):

try `permute( --n, array )`
you are passing a copy of 2 not the decrement

Answer (score 1):

You have to use prefix subtraction:

change:

```
 permute(n--,array);
```

to:

```
 permute(--n,array);
```

In this way, you ***first*** decrement 'n' and ***then*** call permute.

In first case you never subtract and you have an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be post-decrementing `n` in your recursive call, pre-decrement instead:

```
permute(--n,array);
```